# Blackberry Users See Usage Exceeded Image

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, geolocation

I have a web page that displays the users location on a small Google map

e.g.
[Google Static Map](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=53,-2.1833&size=200x150&sensor=false&zoom=15&markers=color:green%7C53,-2.1833)

However my colleagues who have blackberrys seem to get the usage limit exceeded image all the time:[image]

Some of these are work blackberry users and some are personal devices. So is google using the BES address as the source? Surely all blackberry users must have this problem if that was the case?

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects to understand here.  One is that the [Google static maps API is rate limited based](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index#Limits) on IP addresses.  This is intended to spread out the usage limits.  The docs for maps say the limit is "25 000 free static map requests per application per day."
If you aren't using an API key, that limit applies per IP address.

The second thing to understand is that BlackBerry devices all access the internet through a VPN that is tunneled through the mobile operator's data plan. This is what BIS service provides, along with email access.   When a BIS user browses the internet, their IP address will come from one of RIM's datacenters, and not from the mobile operator's datacenter.  There is one datacenter for all of North America.   [RIM publishes their IP addresses.](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/viewdocument.do?noCount=true&externalId=KB11036&sliceId=2&dialogID=63832630&cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&stateId=1%200%2063826436&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl)  This means all BlackBerries with BIS service will show up from a limited set of IP addresses.

Combining these two pieces of knowledge together, we have an API whose limits are based on IP addresses, and a large set of devices that use a limited set of IP addresses.  This is why BlackBerry devices run out of Google Maps API quota, even if another non-BlackBerry device using the same mobile operator does not see the quota issue.